# Sharing rules is created but not working on scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, sharing-rule

I recently try to create a sharing rules on a custom object in a scratch org.

Custom object: Foo__c

- Field: only the default name field.

Foo Sharing Settings:

- Default Internal Access: Private
- Default External Access: Private

Foo Sharing Rules:

- From: owned by members of AllInternalUsers public group
- To: AllInternalUsers public group

When I create my scratch org and manually setup this configuration (or via org:push). The sharing rule is created in the UI, but adding Foo__c record will not add the Foo__Share record associated to the AllInternalUsers public group, preventing internal users to have access to the record.

Now, when I tried this setup in a developer org (not a scratch org), the Foo__Share record will be created.

Additional info:

```
// my org-def.json 

{

    "orgName": "SharingRulesTests",

    "edition": "Developer",

    "features": [ "ExternalSharing", "Communities" ],

    "settings": {

        "orgPreferenceSettings": {

            "networksEnabled": true

        }
    }

}
```

Am I missing an additional setting/feature or is it currently a know issue?

Thanks!